# MultiPointTouchArea and Canvas

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am playing with `MultiPointTouchArea` in a `Canvas` component to make a little drawing exercise. The code below works but the `onReleased` event is getting called twice and I don't understand why.

From the log statements below, I see it gets called first with one `TouchPoint`, then again with two `TouchPoints` – the x and y positions are the same for all. Also the `id` of these touchPoints are undefined.

I don't get it. Since I define a `maximumTouchPoints` and am testing with just one touch (I am testing this on my laptop using a trackpad, with just one "finger".) :

- why am I getting multiple touchpoints
- why is `onReleased` getting called twice?
- why are the touchPoints `id` undefined, since I have defined my touchPoints?

---

```
qml: released 1
qml:     undefined 386.66015625 207.6640625
qml: is this touch1? true

qml: released 2
qml:     undefined 386.66015625 207.6640625
qml: is this touch1? true
qml:     undefined 386.66015625 207.6640625
qml: is this touch1? true
```

---

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Canvas")

    Canvas {
        id: canvas
        anchors.fill: parent

        property real lastX: 0
        property real lastY: 0

        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.lineWidth = 1
            ctx.strokeStyle = "blue"
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY)
            ctx.lineTo(touch1.x,touch1.y)
            ctx.stroke()

            canvas.lastX = touch1.x;
            canvas.lastY = touch1.y;
        }

        function clearCanvas() {
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
             ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        }

        MultiPointTouchArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            minimumTouchPoints: 1
            maximumTouchPoints: 1
            touchPoints: [TouchPoint { id: touch1 }]

            onPressed: {
                canvas.lastX = touch1.x;
                canvas.lastY = touch1.y;

                canvas.clearCanvas();
            }

            onReleased: {

                console.log("released", touchPoints.length); // CALLED TWICE?

                var tp;
                for (var i = 0; i < touchPoints.length; i++) {
                tp = touchPoints[i];
                    console.log("\t",tp.id, tp.x, tp.y);

                    console.log("is this touch1?", tp === touch1);
                }
            }

            onUpdated: canvas.requestPaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that there are open bugs for these issues

The "two release events" issue has been reported and is open: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44781

The "no previousX, previousY" TouchPoint issue is there too: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-41692